# CLI Error when updating Composer because it requires a Plugin API version ("1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0")

Tags: magento2.4, composer, bin-magento

I'm trying to update composer and dependencies but getting this CLI error:

```
The "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a 
Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0").
```

and this error:

```
The "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API 
version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.1.0").
```

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to clear the `CLI` from these errors, I had to make some changes to the `composer.json` file in the root directory. These were the steps:

**1**. Add in `"require"`

```
  "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "2.1.0 as 1.0.4",

  "magento/inventory-composer-installer": "1.2.0 as 1.1.0",
```

**2**. Change in `"require-dev"`

```
From: "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",

To: "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
```

**3**. Run: `composer update`

**4**. Finalize by running: `bin/magento setup:upgrade` That's it!

```
Your CLI should be clear from errors! I hope it helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

magento 2.4.1 and under does not support composer 2, you want to either upgrade your magento or downgrade your composer